# fopen not allowing a variable for file name to create

Tags: php, fopen

I am trying to create a file and write to it line by line.  When trying to create the file using a file name from a variable, it fails.  but if I hard code the file name it works.

The echos are:

> Unable to open/create file: CleanStatements\Clean_IRS01HHTAX.TXT

This works:

```
if ($handle) {
        $cleanFileHandle = fopen( "CleanStatements\\Clean_IRS01HHTAX.TXT", "w") or die("Unable to open/create file: ".$this->CleanFilePath);
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            fwrite($cleanFileHandle, $line);
        }
        fclose($cleanFileHandle);
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        // error opening the file.
    }
```

This Does Not

```
if ($handle) {
        $cleanFileHandle = fopen( $this->CleanFilePath, "w") or die("Unable to open/create file: ".$this->CleanFilePath);
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            fwrite($cleanFileHandle, $line);
        }
        fclose($cleanFileHandle);
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        // error opening the file.
    }
```

Here is the full class:

```
/**
 * Class StatementFile
*/
class StatementFile
{
var $Name;
var $FilePath;
var $Type;
var $CleanFileName;
var $CleanFilePath;

function __construct($filePath){
    $this->Name = basename($filePath).PHP_EOL;
    $this->FilePath = 'Statements\\'.$filePath;
    $this->Type = null;
    $this->CleanFileName = "Clean_".$this->Name;
    $this->CleanFilePath = "CleanStatements\\" . $this->CleanFileName;
}

function cleanStatement(){
    $handle = fopen($this->FilePath, "r");
    echo "Opening file: ".$this->FilePath ."<br/>";
    if ($handle) {
        $cleanFileHandle = fopen( $this->CleanFilePath, "w") or die("Unable to open/create file: ".$this->CleanFilePath);
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            // process the line read.
            // clean line here
            fwrite($cleanFileHandle, $line);
        }
        fclose($cleanFileHandle);
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        // error opening the file.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$this->CleanFilePath`?

Comment: But the filenames and directories are different.

Comment: @Dave: the value is CleanStatements\Clean_IRS01HHTAX.TXT

Comment: @NigelRen The first path is the first echo and the CleanStatements\Clean_IRS01HHTAX.TXT is the second echo.  I'll update the question to better resemble that.

Comment: Change that backslash to a forward slash. Even on Windows PHP is smart enough to deal with forward slashes.

Comment: @Dave I've tried that, I have also added the full class just to make sure that it's not some side effect.

Comment: Use a constant **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** instead backslash, and you should remove PHP_EOL from file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Remove the `PHP_EOL` from `$this->Name`

---

This is just a guess but I would bet that `PHP_EOL` does not contain valid filename characters:

```
$this->Name = basename($filePath).PHP_EOL;
// which ultimate ends up concatenated in
$this->CleanFilePath
```

If you really, really, really need to keep it in `$this->name` for whatever reason then apply `trim()`

```
$cleanFileHandle = fopen( trim( $this->CleanFilePath ), "w") or die("Unable to open/create file: ".trim( $this->CleanFilePath) );
```